# Need Infinitescroll to work with a simple Masonry tumblr

Tags: tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The Masonry works, but the Infinite Scroll doesn't.
I'm trying to make the simplest Masonry/InfiniteScroll theme to build upon. I've tried a lot of different methods but I still get stuck.

```
    <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">

    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/Ebfm2v4gy/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script> 
<script type="https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#container');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.item', columnWidth:300
});
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination',
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : '.item'
});
});
</script>

<style>
    .item{width:300px;}
    img{max-width:100%;}
</style>  

  </head>
  <body>
<div id="container">        
{block:Posts}

{block:Photo}
<div class="item"><img src="{PhotoUrl-500}" title="{PhotoAlt}"/></div>
{/block:Photo}


{/block:Posts}  
</div><!--wall-->  

{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:NextPage}
<a id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}"></a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this code if you want, this is the best one i have found so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/iBElrgjim/jquerymasonry.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/Qyblrgjfn/jqueryinfintescroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    var $wall = $('.posts');
    $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $wall.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.entry',
    isAnimated : false
    });
    });

    $wall.infinitescroll({
    navSelector : "div#navigation",
    nextSelector : "div#navigation a#nextPage",
    itemSelector : ".entry",
    bufferPx : 2000,
    debug : false,
    errorCallback: function() {
    $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
    }},
    function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements );
    $newElems.hide();
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $wall.masonry( 'appended', $newElems,{isAnimated: false}, function(){$newElems.fadeIn('slow');} );
    });
    }); $('.posts').show(500);
    });
    </script>
<script>
    $.fn.changebackgroundColor = function(msg) {
    $("#perma").css("#000");
  };
</script>
```

I have no issue with the infinite scroll with it and it's rather simple. You should just check the Selector and var names to put those that are in your theme. else than that, I think the problem could be the scripts you are using. Try to use different ones maybe. I used to have some similar to yours and I realized that they didn't even respond when i debugged my page. It could be a similar issue.